# Stop jQuery rounding to the nearest decimal on .css()

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I stop jQuery rounding to the nearest decimal value on the `Transfrom: translateY`? This is causing performance issues with Safari on iPad as it has become very jittery

```
$(window).on("load resize scroll",function(e){

if ($(window).width() > 768) {
  var item = $('.sticky-stuff');
  var container = $(".sticky-container");
  var triggerTop = container.offset().top;
  var triggerBottom = triggerTop + container.height() - item.height();

  $(window).scroll(function() {
      var curentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
      var isTop = curentScroll <= triggerTop;
      var isBottom = curentScroll >= triggerBottom;
      var relativeScroll = isTop ? triggerTop : isBottom ? triggerBottom: curentScroll;
      var offsetY = relativeScroll - triggerTop;

      item.css({
'-webkit-transform' : 'translateY(' + offsetY + 'px)',
        'transform' : 'translateY(' + offsetY + 'px)',
      });
  })
}
});
```

Comment: Are you sure it's jQuery doing it or the browser?

Comment: Do you want to remove the decimals or do you want to keep them instead of rounding?

Comment: jQuery doesn't round anything... in Chrome on Windows you can set values like 0.00000001, and it is set directly. Anyway how the hell do you get decimal from that functions? Seems impossible.

Comment: @HanoJohannesRossouw I want to keep the decimals

@FlashThunder using `console.log(triggerTop);` shows that it is a full integer

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that chrome for instance on CSS will always round up pixel based values, in other words it will not respect fractional pixels but rather round or throw them away. Percentage decimals are however respected in the browser, so its not Jquery that is causing this but rather CSS itself in the way it interprest the rules.

Comment: You can maybe try and play with the different measurements found here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Comment: When I use something like Skrollr in chrome it is able to use decimal places - how so?

Comment: that is a js library that creates the animations when scrolling so javascript can interpret the decimals but css cannot, or raw css rules cannot

Comment: here you can find how each browser interprets its css rules http://cruft.io/posts/percentage-calculations-in-ie/

Comment: Ah so the issue is with safari - its laggy/ choppy.

Comment: safari rounds to 15 decimal places, which its not doing... so the issue is with the jquery